# What does "reserved in total by PyTorch" mean in torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory?

Tags: memory-management, pytorch, gpu, out-of-memory

I'm trying to implement a 3D neural network that will work with 400x400x400 tensors. I tried testing my model with a batch_size of 1 and I'm getting the following error:
`torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 2.86 GiB (GPU 0; 23.65 GiB total capacity; 3.55 GiB already allocated; 1.66 GiB free; 3.59 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF`

I don't understand why I only have 1.66 GiB free when total capacity is 23.65 GiB and only 3.59 GiB were reserved in by PyTorch... Do I have any memory leak? Is this behaviour common?

btw: I'm working in a computer cluster with a TITAN RTX.

Comment: Someone/thing else is also running on the same GPU and consuming memory outside of your Pytorch session